# Fiber Port Issue

Tags: switch, brocade, fiber, foundry

I'm trying to troubleshoot a situation between a foundry sx and a brocade icx.  I setup tagged ports and vlans between them both.  Now when I connect the 2 switches with an ethernet cable, ospf comes up and everything works nicely however when I connect them using fiber, they fail to establish any adjacencies nor can I ping between them even with private ip's.

On the sfp ports for the icx, it says to configure the ports manually to:  1000-full-master and the other end to 1000-full-slave which I did.  The link comes up but I can't pass any traffic between them.

Any ideas on why this may be at all?

Comment: Gigabit really should be left on autonegotiate. Do your optics match on both ends, i.e SX to SX? Are you using the correct type of fiber optic cable with those optics, i.e. multimode with SX optics? Maybe post up a portion of the relevant configuration.

Comment: Well documentation specifically says to set the port manually. I also tested with auto and the link doesn't come up if it's auto.  One thing I'm unsure of is, on the icx they are 10gig sfp ports which use sfp+.  I'm using 1G SFP, with mmf fiber...optics are the same on both ends. The devices recognize both sfp's and the link does come up when set manually.  The ends are LC-LC.  The optics themselves are e1mg-sx for both devices.

Comment: What software version are you running on ICX? Which SFP port are you using?

Comment: Prem L3...so we can run ospf.  The actual software version I can't get to you right this moment unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe `DEFECT000395157 = ICX6450 port 1/2/2 and 1/2/4 configured for 1 gig requires reload to come up. This will be fixed in next code release of 7.4.0 patch.`

Comment: This was starting to smell like a h/w issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Turned out to be a bad module on the SX...can't believe all 12 sfp ports didn't work! Swapped to different one and everything works fine now. Thanks for the suggestions.